# Realtime p2p data sharing on Android/html5

Tags: html, p2p, database-replication, collaboration

I have a Wifi connection for several Android and PC devices without internet connectivity.
All of the devices need to collaboratively modify the same data (something like editing google docs file online for several users).
PCs work with pure HTML5 app, Androids with hybrid HTML5/native.

I need to create an effective way to synchronize the data in real time without having centralized server.

The date exchange has to be secure, so no unauthorized connections could read the shared data.

The only idea I got is to have some kind of UDP broadcast via sockets, but it's not possible with WebSockets for HTML5, so I have to figure out another solution. Maybe some peer to peer replication of DB or file sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use adobe RTMFP channel to broadcast the data to multiple peers either over LAN or internet.  It only needs the flash player installment on android & PC. Another alternative is webrtc but it requires broker server to establish the connection.